# Маршрутизация OpenVPN

Tags: windows, маршрутизация, openvpn, windows-server, windows-server-2003

Есть сервер. ОС Windows 2003. На нем установлены две сетевых карты с адресами

- 192.168.0.10
- 192.168.1.96

На интерфейсе 192.168.0.10 указан шлюз 192.168.0.1, который смотрит в интернет.

На сервере поднят OpenVPN сервер, который раздает адреса в подсети 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0

Требуется, чтобы удаленные VPN клиенты имели доступ к компьютерам 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

Я в конфиге OpenVPN сервера прописал

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

После этого с клиента удается пропинговать внутренний адрес сервера 192.168.1.96. Но вот дальше пакеты не идут. Wireshark на сервере показывает такое

```
298 1590.593905000  10.8.0.8    192.168.1.88    ICMP    74  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=260/1025, ttl=128 (no response found!)
```

Т.е. получается, что с удаленных клиентов пакеты приходят, но куда их девать сам сервер не понимает.

```
ping 192.168.1.88
```

с сервера проходит успешно

`route print` на сервере показывает такое

```
IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x10003 ...00 0e 0c 3b f8 82 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection - Virtual Machine Network Services Driver
0x10005 ...00 ff 09 d5 6b 3f ...... TAP-Windows Adapter V9 - Virtual Machine Network Services Driver
0x30004 ...00 0e 0c 3b f8 81 ...... Marvell Yukon 88E8050 PCI-E ASF Gigabit Ethernet Controller - Virtual Machine Network Services Driver
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.10     10
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.1     30
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     30
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.1     30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.0.10     192.168.0.10     10
     192.168.0.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.10     192.168.0.10     10
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.96     192.168.1.96     10
     192.168.1.96  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.96     192.168.1.96     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.1     30
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.0.10     192.168.0.10     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.1.96     192.168.1.96     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.1      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.10     192.168.0.10      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.96     192.168.1.96      1
Основной шлюз:         192.168.0.1
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter` установлен в 1

Служба "Маршрутизация и удаленный доступ" запущена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Полное решение здесь https://support.microsoft.com/ru-kz/help/323415/how-to-set-up-routing-and-remote-access-for-an-intranet-in-windows-ser

Итак, для начала нужно запустить службу "Маршрутизация и удаленный доступ" и перевести тип запуска в Авто. Изначально она у меня не запускалась, а в системном логе выдавалась ошибка

> Служба "Маршрутизация и удаленный доступ" завершена из-за внутренней ошибки 711 (0x2C7).
>
> Дополнительные сведения можно найти в центре справки и поддержки, в "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp".

Чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки нужно убедиться, что службы

- Телефония
- Диспетчер подключения удаленного доступа
- Диспетчер автоматического подключения удаленного доступа

не отключены. Т.е. тип запуска у них "Вручную" или "Авто".

Далее идем в оснастку Администрирование -> Маршрутизация и удаленный доступ, там щелкаем правой кнопкой по нашему серверу и выбираем "Настроить маршрутизацию и удаленный доступ"